# Improve GeoServer WMTS service TIFF quality

Tags: raster, geoserver, wmts

How can I improve raster clarity in WMTS service in OpenLayers or QGIS? It seem that after I tile the raster, it downsample my origin data.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Please tell us about your raster? what requests are you making? and how you added the raster to Geoserver